# Getting data from model to controller

Tags: codeigniter

I do have a question : I cannot pass the data from model to controller
You can see some of my codes, please help me.
It does not work!

this is my model "mymodel.php"

```
 ....

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `rand` WHERE `used` = 0 LIMIT 0, 1");
    if($query){
    foreach ($query->result() as $row);
    }
    $t = "EXAMPLE/{$row->code}";
    function wandad() {
        return $t;
    }
.....
```

and this is my controller mycont.php

```
 ...
 $this->load->model('mymodel');

$data['new'] = $this->Mymodel->wandad();
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
 ...
```

and this is my view    myview.php

```
 ....
 echo $new; 
 .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you The model is not written properly and to corrent this simple do this

> 1.) I put a default value on $t
>
> 2.) I put the query >> loop on the inside function
>
> wandad

so it can be executed once called from controller

```
function wandad() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `rand` WHERE `used` = 0 LIMIT 0, 1");
    $t = "";
    if($query){

       foreach ($query->result() as $row){
          $t = "EXAMPLE/{$row->code}".'<br>';
       }
     }

    return $t;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are several issues into your model

- Your Foreach function doesn't do anything
- `$t` is not in the same **namespace** than `wandad()`
- Function wandad is not defined into your model class

I'm not sure of what you wanna get with `wandad()` function but here's a pattern.

```
function yourFunction()
{
    /* This will return the full query as an array */
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `rand` WHERE `used` = 0 LIMIT 0, 1")->result_array();
    /* Store variable in the same class */
    $this->t = "EXAMPLE/".$query[0]['code'];
/* Close yourFunction() */
}
public function wandad() {
    return $this->t;
}
```

Then into your controller, do that instead :

```
$this->load->model('mymodel');
$this->mymodel->yourFunction();
$data['new'] = $this->mymodel->wandad();
$this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

Comment: Well my apologies, but to me, `foreach ($query->result() as $row);` doesn't stand for any action

Comment: OK, Thank you for your comment.
But my problem did not solve!

Comment: What you mean by "did not solve" ? The code I sent you works in my application. Where does it fail ? What's the error ?

Comment: Please, post the error.. Did you really copy/pasted my code ? Didn't you forget **$** of `$this->t` ? Could you print the result of `var_dump($query)` ? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Undefined property: Short::$Mymodel
This is the main problem.
I did all your orders.

Comment: Lowercase your mymodel calls. Code Igniter always lowercase model names. Could you print the related line to the error?

Comment: what do you mean by print?
I'm sure, my sodes are correct but I do not know why I can not pass the return data from model to controller.

Answer (score 0):

@Touki his foreach actually does something. It will set the variable $row with the last row that is returned from the query. Not the best way to do it ... But it's a way. Better would be to use a limit in the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code @Ernesto.that is

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
      $t. = "EXAMPLE/{$row->code}".'<br>';
   }
```

but your code was simply nice